# Reporting in Microsoft AdCenter (Sandbox) - RoR

Tags: ruby, api

I am using AdCenter API for my RoR application. I searched a lot on Internet to find example of ruby code to fetch account performance report using API, But didn't get.. Now I have written following code but `submitGenerateReport` returns `nil`

Here is my code.

```
 report_request = AccountPerformanceReportRequest.new
  start_date = 10.days.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  end_date = Time.zone.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  scope = AccountReportScope.new
  scope.accountIds = [AppConfig.adcenter['accountId']]

  # Specify the format of the report.
  report_request.format = 'Xml'
  report_request.returnOnlyCompleteData = false
  report_request.language = 'English'
  report_request.reportName = "My Account Report"
  report_request.aggregation = 'Daily'
  report_request.time = ReportTime.new(start_date, end_date)
  report_request.columns = %w[ AccountName AccountName GregorianDate CurrentMaxCpc Impressions Clicks ]
  report_request.scope = scope
  report_request.filter = nil

  report = SubmitGenerateReportRequest.new(report_request)
  # Returns nil
  puts response = svc.submitGenerateReport(report)
```

I have campaigns, adgroups as well as ads in specified account.
Can anyone please guide me where I am wrong or give some example of reporting adcenter through api using ruby?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Got the solution... The time was not in right format so, start time and end time was unrecognisable in soap request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution...

The time was not in right format so, start time and end time was unrecognisable in soap request. SOAP debugging helped me a lot..